# Only allow a user to edit their own content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using RoR 4 and the Devise gem for user authentication. I want a user to be able to edit their own content and not anyone else's content. The authenticate_user method only seems to make sure the user is logged in before they can edit the content. But another user can just sign up and edit everyone else's content.

My controller looks like:

```
    class PrayersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_prayer, only: [:show, :edit, :updated, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @prayers = Prayer.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @prayer = current_user.prayers.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @prayer = current_user.prayers.build(prayer_params)

      if @prayer.save
        redirect_to @prayer, notice: "Successfully created prayer"
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def update
        @prayer = Prayer.find_by_id(params[:id])

        if @prayer.update(prayer_params)
          redirect_to @prayer, notice: "Prayer was successfully updated"
        else
          render 'edit'
        end        
  end

  def destroy
    @prayer.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def prayer_params
      params.require(:prayer).permit(:title, :body)
    end

    def find_prayer
      @prayer = Prayer.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

I tried to make a before_action of my own that looked something like this:

```
    def own_prayer
  if !current_user == Prayer.current_user
    redirect_to @prayer, notice: "You cannot edit this prayer"
  end  
end
```

But that did not work. I can limit access to the form via the view with a similar action but I don't think this is entirely safe?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't have class method `current_user` on `Prayer` class. Also seems you have `has_many :prayers` in your User model. So to get prayer's user you need to call `user` method on Prayer instance variable.

It's supposed to be like that:

```
@prayer = Prayer.find params[:id]

unless current_user == @prayer.user
   redirect_to(@prayer, notice: "You cannot edit this prayer") and return
end
```

If you need more tricky restriction rules then use [cancan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Comment: Thank you very much. Will this go in the update method of my prayers_controller?

Comment: I guess you need to restrict edit method too, so you can add `before_filter own_prayer, only: [:edit, :update]` method with code above. And then just remove `@prayer = Prayer.find_by_id(params[:id])
` from update method